# Woocommerce - Hide category when a single product is in cart

Tags: woocommerce

I'm configuring a WordPress/WooCommerce site for a company that sets up Weddings. It has 4 different Ceremony Packages you can choose from that are all in one category called Ceremonies and there are a wide range of add-on decor items you can book as well.

I am asking, if the user adds Ceremony Package 1 to the cart, how do I then hide the other 3 from the catalog so that the user won't add Ceremony Package 2 by mistake as you don't need more than 1 wedding package. Also if the user removes Ceremony Package 1 from the cart then all 4 Ceremony Packages should display in the category again.

At the same time, I only need this to apply to this category because the user should still be able to add any of the additional decor items to the cart.

Perhaps, once an item in this category has been added to the cart then just the category is hidden? I am uncertain on how to code this. A pseudo code example would be: If 'ceremony' category product is in cart then 'ceremony' category visibility in the catalog is false.

Hope thats makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

WooThemes has some plugins for only showing certain products or packages. Here you can see them and which one suits what need: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/chained-products-vs-product-bundles-vs-force-sells-vs-grouped-products/

Br Robin